# Seting a bitmap image to static control c++ Win32

Tags: c++, image, winapi, bitmap

I have a problem setting an image to static window.
Here is a part of my code:

```
HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "Tetris/Tetrominoes/T One.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 20, 20, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
one = CreateWindow("Static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, (x-10), ((y-y)+50), 20, 20, hMain, NULL,NULL,NULL);
SendMessage(one, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)bitmap);
BringWindowToTop(one);
```

The thing I don't understand is why it isn't loading since I used this type of code before for different purpose. According to all sources this part of code should work fine but my image is not showing. if I remove the `SendMessage()` function my window is visible but without image and when I put `SendMessage()` the window just disappears. I tried chaging the image size window size and still nothing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you verify that `LoadImage()` is returning a non-null bitmap handle to begin with? Have you tried using an *absolute* path instead of a *relative* path?

Comment: I have tested and When the bitmap handle is NULL, the static window is invisible.